# How to display a dijit.Dialog as a popup up

Tags: java, dojo, dialog, popupwindow

I am trying to display a dijit.Dialog as a popup window. This is a new feature addition to an existing project and as I have never woked wth Dojo;s before I am struggling a bit.
I have created the pop up window but it keeps displaying as a seperate page than a popup, what am I doing wrong? Please help!

THe page where the button to show the popup

```
<input class="style_off pink_button ft_white" onclick='submitOnclick()'  id="show_popup" type="submit" name="showPopup" value="Generate PopUp"/>
<span id="validationPopUp" style="display:none;"><c:out value=""/></span>
```

The script page:

```
function submitOnclick() {

        dojo.xhrPost({
              url: "${get_valpopup_url}",                
              form: dojo.byId("searchResults"),
              load: function(data){
                //Destroy widget to avoid reallocating it during parse.                 

                if(valDialog) {
                    valDialog.destroy();
                } 
                dojo.place(data, "validationPopUp", "only");
                dojo.parser.parse("validationPopUp");
                valDialog = dijit.byId('inputPopUpId');
                valDialog.show();
               },
               error: function(e) {
                  console.log("Ajax call failed", e);
               }
         });

        return false;
    }
```

the pop up window

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div id="inputPopUpId" dojotype="dijit.Dialog" title="${popup_title}" 
    height="500px;" xmlns:f="http://www.twister.total.com/taglib"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
    xmlns:tiles="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:util="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/util"
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:s="http://www.twister.total.com/taglib/sessionAttr"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <spring:message code="random_extract_popup_title" var="popup_title" htmlEscape="false" />
    <p>
        <spring:message code="random_extract_popup_message" />
     </p>


     <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="inputPopup" action="reports" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                <s:insertSessionConversationId attributeName="searchResults"/>
                        <s:insertSessionConversationId attributeName="searchDto"/>
      <div>
        <label for="noOfRecords">
          <spring:message code="random_extract_popup_form_label" />
        </label>
        <input id="noOfRecords" type='text' name='noOfRecords' style="width:150px" />
        <spring:message code="random_extract_popup_form_message" var="name_msg" htmlEscape="false" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
          <c:set var="sec_name_msg">
            <spring:escapeBody javaScriptEscape="true">${name_msg}</spring:escapeBody>
          </c:set>
          Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({elementId : "noOfRecords", widgetType : "dijit.form.NumberTextBox", widgetAttrs : {promptMessage: "${sec_name_msg}", required : true, constraints: {pattern: "0, ####"}}})); 
        </script>
      </div>

      <br />     
      <br />

      <div class="submit">        
        <spring:message code="button_extract_random_report" var="extract_random_report" htmlEscape="false" />
                    <script type="text/javascript">Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration({elementId:'extract_random_report', event:'onclick'}));</script>
                    <input class="startLoading style_off pink_button ft_white" id="extract_random_report" type="submit" name="extractrandom" value="${fn:escapeXml(extract_random_report)}"/>


      </div>
     </form:form> 
</div>
```

The views.xml

```
<definition extends="empty" name="a/s/validationPopUpId">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="validation-dialog.jspx"/>
    </definition>
```

The code in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "sox/search/reports", params="showPopup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String generatePopup(@ModelAttribute(TwisterConstants.SEARCH_RESULTS) AuditSoxListResultsDto searchResults, @ModelAttribute(TwisterConstants.SEARCH_DTO) AuditSoxSearchRequest searchDto, 
           Model uiModel, Locale selectedLocale, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){


      uiModel.addAttribute(TwisterConstants.SEARCH_RESULTS, TwisterConstants.SEARCH_DTO);

      addDateTimeFormatPatterns(uiModel,"S-");

      return "a/s/validationPopUpId";
   }
```

Comment: I suspect the reason it just opens in the same page is that you are clicking on a submit button and there is an error in the javascript so the submit event isn't stopped (i.e. doesn't return false). If you put `alert('foo');` before the `return false;`, do you see that alert when clicking the button? Also where is the code that actually creates the popup?

Comment: The alert is displayed when i click on the button. The code for the pop up window is what under the title "the popup window". I was actually following a similar code existing in the project. I assumed when i click on the button the code will be placed where the span validationpopup is.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. You have done `dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");` too somewhere, right?

Comment: Ah, you also need `dojo.require("dojo.parser");` and try having `onclick="return submitOnClick()"` on the button. See if you can make sense of this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/37wtqknf/1/

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the response but unforutately I have tried all above and a few combinations but the page is still not coming up as a popup. Any other recommendations?

Comment: Hmm. Are you absolutely sure the page reloads when you click the button? If you place an `alert(42);` before the line with `if(valDialog) {`, do you see that alert? Are there any errors in the Firebug console (or your dev tools of choice)? If the page does indeed reload, then the problem is with the onclick event handler failing to prevent the form submission. If it doesn't, perhaps there is something in inputPopUpId that fails to parse. If it isn't too secret, perhaps you can paste the actual inputPopUpId content that the server produces?

Comment: Have you tried creating minimistic example?

Comment: Hi Frode, You were right I am not seeing the alert inside the load function. How do I debug this? I am sorry but javascript in not my area

Comment: So you know the submitOnClick function is called and returns false (checked with the `alert('foo')` earlier). And you made sure that the button has `onclick="return submitOnClick()"`. That should prevent the form from being submitted. However, since you are seeing a page load, the form is in fact submitted. Does the jsfiddle I posted earlier work for you? Which browser are you testing in?